# How can I fix the 'Each child in a list should have a unique 'key' prop' warning in React?

Tags: reactjs, key, warnings

I am developing a react app and I am unable to fix this warning can you please help locate where specifically I need a key

my code block where the error is generated-

```
const [experiences, setExperiences] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    const query = '*[_type == "experiences"]';
    const skillsQuery = '*[_type == "skills"]';

    client.fetch(query).then((data) => {
      setExperiences(data);
    });

    client.fetch(skillsQuery).then((data) => {
      setSkills(data);
    });
  }, []);


<div className="app__skills-exp">
          {experiences.map((experience) => (
            <motion.div
              className="app__skills-exp-item"
              key={experience.year}
            >
              <div className="app__skills-exp-year">
                <p className="bold-text">{experience.year}</p>
              </div>
              <motion.div className="app__skills-exp-works" key={experience.works}>
                {experience.works.map((work) => (
                  <>
                    <motion.div
                      whileInView={{ opacity: [0, 1] }}
                      transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
                      className="app__skills-exp-work"
                      data-tip
                      // data-for is depricated as v4 using data-tooltip-id instead
                      data-tooltip-id={work.name}
                      key={work.name}
                    >
                      <h4 className="bold-text">{work.name}</h4>
                      <p className="p-text">{work.company}</p>
                      
                    </motion.div>
                    <Tooltip
                      id={work.name}
                      effect="solid"
                      arrowColor="#fff"
                      className="skills-tooltip"
                    >
                      {work.desc}
                    </Tooltip>
                  </>
                ))}
              </motion.div>
            </motion.div>
          ))}
        </div>
```

I have tried using key in tooltip but that didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every elements of a list should have a key prop.

So when you do this :

```
{experience.works.map((work) => (
  <>
    <motion.div
      whileInView={{ opacity: [0, 1] }}
      transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
      className="app__skills-exp-work"
    // ...
  </>
))}
```

The component you use is called a `Fragment`, the `<></>` is a shortcut to write it, ant it cannot contains a `key` prop written that way.

It is common to use the shortcut instead of the full name, but in that specific case you should write it like this:

```
{experience.works.map((work) => (
  <Fragment key={work.name}>
    <motion.div
      whileInView={{ opacity: [0, 1] }}
      transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
      className="app__skills-exp-work"
     // ...
  </Fragment>
))}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Florent M. This fixes it .
I should read the documentation better. Cheers